# When I restart the bot it makes me start leveling again discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to do the level system and I succeeded by following a tutorial.
But when I restart my bot it makes me start leveling again by creating new data on the json not removing the old ones and after 2 hours of different attempts I don't know how to solve.
[image]

EDIT: I decided to update the code by removing the functions and see how it went. Although I notice an improvement, it sometimes resets the data to hell and I don't understand why.

Code:

```py
#with functions
import discord
import random
from discord import client
from discord.ext import commands
import json
from discord.utils import get
from random import choice

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='°')
users = {}

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot online')
    global users
    try:
        with open('ranking.json') as f:
            users = json.load(f)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Impossibile caricare ranking.json")
        users = {}

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    xp = random.randrange(5, 10)
    await update_data(users, message.author)
    await add_experience(users, message.author, xp)
    await level_up(users, message.author, message)
    _save()
    await client.process_commands(message)

async def update_data(users, user):
    if user.id not in users:
        print("pass")
        users[user.id] = {}
        users[user.id]["experience"] = 0
        users[user.id]["level"] = 0

async def add_experience(users, user, xp):
    users[user.id]["experience"] += xp

async def level_up(users, user, message):
    experience = users[user.id]["experience"]
    lvl_start = users[user.id]["level"]
    lvl_end = int(experience ** (1/4))
    print(lvl_start)
    print(lvl_end)
    if lvl_start < lvl_end:
        await message.channel.send(f"{user.mention} è salito al livello {lvl_end}")
        users[user.id]["level"] = lvl_end

def _save():
    with open('ranking.json', 'w+') as f:
        json.dump(users, f)
```

```py
#without functions
import discord
import random
from discord import client
from discord.ext import commands
import json
from discord.utils import get
from random import choice

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='°')
users = {}

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot online')
    global users
    try:
        with open('ranking.json') as f:
            users = json.load(f)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Impossibile caricare ranking.json")
        users = {}

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    id_user = str(message.author.id)
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    xp = random.randrange(5, 10)
    if id_user not in users:
        print(message.author.name)
        users[id_user] = {}
        users[id_user]["experience"] = 0
        users[id_user]["level"] = 0
    users[id_user]["experience"] += xp
    experience = users[id_user]["experience"]
    lvl_start = users[id_user]["level"]
    lvl_end = int(experience ** (1 / 4))
    if lvl_start < lvl_end:
        await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.mention} è salito al livello {lvl_end}")
        users[id_user]["level"] = lvl_end
    _save()
    await client.process_commands(message)

def _save():
    with open('ranking.json', 'w+') as f:
        json.dump(users, f)
```

ranking.json

```json
{"488826524791734275": {"experience": 56, "level": 2}, "488826524791734275": {"experience": 32, "level": 2}}
```

As you can see from the json my user id is repeated two times and from the screen my messages where I restarted the bot during execution.
Is it possible to be able to rank every 30 seconds? i have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

JSON keys can't be INT so change `user.id` to `str(user.id)`

Comment: I put this code all over the place and ok it works but now everytime reset after 2 restarts. I don't know why it does this (at least it doesn't duplicate ids)